# mvvmcross phone 8.1 resume shows mainpage.xaml

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvmcross

We have a windows phone 8 application build with mvvmcross and the start up page is different from mainpage.xaml. When registered as IAppstart it works perfectly fine in start and resume.

However when its upgraded to 8.1, I see that App_Activated event is called in the app.xaml in the resume event and only MainPage.xaml is shown. 
Any way I can modify the resume event to show IAppStart registered viewmodel?

Things that I have tried:
1. Try to resolve IAppStart and call the start. (No exception but doesn't navigate to actual view)
2. Modify WMAppManifest.xml to have the "Navigation Page" as actual View. Windows navigation is not able to find the xaml, rightly so because the actual xaml is inside "Views" folder per convention of mvvmcross
3. Modify WMAppManifest.xml to have the "Navigation Page" as "Views/ActualView.xaml", mvvmcross is not able to resolve the viewmodel for this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Read the Todo-MVVMCross and you'll get your answer

Answer (score -1):

I haven't found any other options than to cancel requests to show MainPage.xaml. This can be done by hooking up the RootFrame.Navigating event in the constructor in the App.xaml.cs file:

```
RootFrame.Navigating += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Uri.ToString().StartsWith("/MainPage.xaml"))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: We came up with one another thing, in the mainpage.xaml.cs, in the OnNavigatedTo, wrote the code to go back the stack: App.RootFrame.GoBack();